# Adding legend entry for border of fill, from fillbetween

Tags: pgfplots, legend, fillbetween

I've made a plot like the one below to show a distribution of values in the dependent variable versus the change of the independent variable.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfplotstableread{
x min q1 med q3 max
1 0 2 4 6 8
2 2 4 5 6 8
3 1 3 5 7 9
}\data%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[title=Example,
    xlabel=x,
    ylabel=y,
    ]
    \addplot[blue, dashed] table [x=x, y=min] {\data};
    \addplot[blue, dotted, name path global=q1] table [x=x, y=q1] {\data};
    \addplot[blue, solid] table [x=x, y=med] {\data};
    \addplot[blue, dotted, name path global=q3] table [x=x, y=q3] {\data};
    \addplot[blue, dashed] table [x=x, y=max] {\data};
    \addplot[blue, fill opacity=0.3] fill between[of=q1 and q3];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Image showing resulting PDF plot from code, above]

I'd like to have a legend like the following,

[image: Example legend]

Is that possible? How?

**Edit: adding my full solution**

The [solution below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/461667/145367) got most of what I was looking for, and with a few minor edits I was able to get it perfect. (Well, the image below isn't quite perfect--just realized I switched Q1 and Q3.)

[image: Final result showing correct legend]

I increased the size of the custom legend entry from 0.1cm to 0.4cm,

```
\pgfplotsset{custom legend/.style={%
                /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
                        \path[##1] (0cm,-.4cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.4cm);
                        \draw[dotted] (0cm,-0.4cm) -- (0.6cm,-0.4cm)
                         (0cm,0.4cm) -- (0.6cm,0.4cm);
                         \draw[blue] (0cm,0cm) -- (0.6cm,0cm);
                }}}
```

And made the corresponding legend entry three lines,

```
\begin{axis}[title=Example,
  xlabel=x,
  ylabel=y,
  legend style={cells={align=left}},
  ]
  \addlegendimage{blue,dashed}
  \addlegendentry[font=\sffamily]{Maximum}
  \addlegendimage{custom legend,draw=none,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.3}
  \addlegendentry[xshift=-2mm,font=\sffamily]{Q1 \\ Median \\ Q3}
  \addlegendimage{blue,dashed}
  \addlegendentry[xshift=-0.2mm,font=\sffamily]{Minimum}
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a proposal. I looked up`area legend` in `pgfplots.code.tex` and used it as a basis for `custom legend`, which comes already close to what you want, I think, and can be further customized. (I am pretty sure I have seen an answer using similar tricks but even after some long search I couldn't find it. I am definitely not claiming that I am the first one doing these tricks.) Anyway, the result of a quick customization (after a long search without hits) is

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfplotstableread{
x min q1 med q3 max
1 0 2 4 6 8
2 2 4 5 6 8
3 1 3 5 7 9
}\data%
\pgfplotsset{custom legend/.style={%
                /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
                        \path[##1] (0cm,-0.1cm) rectangle (0.6cm,0.1cm);
                        \draw[dotted] (0cm,-0.1cm) -- (0.6cm,-0.1cm)
                         (0cm,0.1cm) -- (0.6cm,0.1cm);
                         \draw[blue] (0cm,0cm) -- (0.6cm,0cm);
                }}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[title=Example,
    xlabel=x,
    ylabel=y,
    ]
    \addlegendimage{blue,dashed}
    \addlegendentry[font=\sffamily]{Maximum}
    \addlegendimage{custom legend,draw=none,fill=blue,fill opacity=0.3}
    \addlegendentry[xshift=-2mm,font=\sffamily]{Median}
    \addlegendimage{blue,dashed}
    \addlegendentry[xshift=-0.2mm,font=\sffamily]{Minimum}
    \addplot[blue, dashed] table [x=x, y=min] {\data};
    \addplot[blue, dotted, name path global=q1] table [x=x, y=q1] {\data};
    \addplot[blue, solid] table [x=x, y=med] {\data};
    \addplot[blue, dotted, name path global=q3] table [x=x, y=q3] {\data};
    \addplot[blue, dashed] table [x=x, y=max] {\data};
    \addplot[blue, fill opacity=0.3] fill between[of=q1 and q3];
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

After some amount of hibernation I will be happy to assist you in further customization, if needed.

Comment: Awesome! This got me on the right path, and with a few small changes I got exactly what I wanted. I increased the size of the custom image in the y dimension, and made the corresponding text a three-line entry (as described in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280108/multi-line-legend-entry-in-pgfplots)).

Comment: @john_stech Thanks! (I was too tired last night to do the tuning, and I am really glad you got what I wanted. I'm wondering you want to add the information what you did to your question, other users might find that useful.)

Comment: Would you mind explaining what ##1 means? I understand that it allows something to become a parameter after the initial macro is expanded, but what becomes the parameter in this case?